# WinAPI Cadena pasada a ventana solo muestra el primer carácter

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, visual-c++, ventana, winapi

Usando como plantilla un proyecto de windows form generado por Visual Studio he querido crear mi ventana desde cero para luego implementar mas cosas pero me encuentro con el problema de no poder asignar a la ventana el valor completo de una cadena de caracteres ya que la barra de titulo solo muestra el primer carácter.
He revisado al Debuguear el contenido de las Variables y el array si contiene el titulo asignado pero al ejecutar la ventana aparece únicamente con la inicial de sea lo que sea yo ponga
Teniendo el siguiente código en Visual Studio Community 2017

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include "Pruebas/Ventana.h"

void Asignar(WCHAR *wchar, const WCHAR* valor /*L"Mi cadena"*/) {
    const size_t stringLength = wcslen(valor) + 1; // obtener la longitud de la cadena
    int err = wcscpy_s(wchar, stringLength, valor); // copiar la cadena de texto en el array+
    int aux = 0;
    /*version insegura pero nossotros controlaremos mas cosas*//*wcscpy(wchar, valor); Arroja error para no usar esta wea*/
}



int valor = 0;

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam){
    switch (message){
        case WM_COMMAND:{
            int wmId = LOWORD(wParam);
        }break;
        case WM_PAINT:{
            PAINTSTRUCT ps;
            HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
            // TODO: Agregar cualquier código de dibujo que use hDC aquí...
            EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        }break;
        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
        default:
            return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}
const int MAX_LOADSTRING = 100;
WCHAR szTitle[MAX_LOADSTRING];
WCHAR szWindowClass[MAX_LOADSTRING];
ATOM MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance)
{
    WNDCLASSEXW wcex;

    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);

    wcex.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wcex.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wcex.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wcex.hInstance = hInstance;
    wcex.hIcon = 0;// LoadIcon(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(107));
    wcex.hCursor = LoadCursor(nullptr, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex.hbrBackground = 0;//(HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1);
    wcex.lpszMenuName = 0;//MAKEINTRESOURCEW(IDC_OPENGLPURO);
    wcex.lpszClassName = szWindowClass;
    wcex.hIconSm = 0; // LoadIcon(wcex.hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_SMALL));
    ATOM A = RegisterClassExW(&wcex);
    return A;
}
HINSTANCE hInst;
LPWSTR mnWndwNme = L"Main Window Name";
BOOL InitInstance(HINSTANCE hInstance, int nCmdShow)
{
    
    hInst = hInstance; // Almacenar identificador de instancia en una variable global
    
    WCHAR aux_szTitle[MAX_LOADSTRING] = L"hola";
    //szTitle;

    HWND hWnd = CreateWindowW(szWindowClass, szTitle, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, CW_USEDEFAULT, 0, nullptr, nullptr, hInstance, nullptr);

    if (!hWnd)
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);

    return TRUE;
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow) {

    //LoadStringW(hInstance, IDS_APP_TITLE, szTitle, MAX_LOADSTRING);
    //LoadStringW(hInstance, IDC_OPENGLPURO, szWindowClass, MAX_LOADSTRING);
    Asignar(szWindowClass, L"pppp");
    Asignar(szTitle, L"Holaaa");
    Ventana *v = new Ventana();

    //v->Crear(hInstance, szTitle, szWindowClass, WndProc, nCmdShow);

    MyRegisterClass(hInstance);
    if (!InitInstance(hInstance, nCmdShow)){
        return FALSE;
    }
    
    HACCEL hAccelTable = LoadAccelerators(hInstance, 0);

    MSG msg;

    // Bucle principal de mensajes:
    while (GetMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0))
    {
        if (!TranslateAccelerator(msg.hwnd, hAccelTable, &msg))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

En la funcion `BOOL InitInstance(HINSTANCE hInstance, int nCmdShow)` tengo la linea que ejecuta `HWND hWnd = CreateWindowW(szWindowClass, szTitle,...);` donde se pasa `aux_szTitle` o `szTitle` siendo esta ultima variable usada en ámbito global.
El error es que al mostrar al ventana por pantalla, solo se muestra el primer carácter
¿Qué estoy haciendo mal? ya que quiero comprender el porque de mi error y luego no seguir cometiendo el mismo errror una y otra vez.

Comment: `WCHAR` solo guarda un carácter...

Comment: El único problema que tienes es en la declaración  LPWSTR mnWndwNme = L"Main Window Name"; que deberia ser LPCWSTR mnWndwNme = L"Main Window Name"; para que puedas asignarle la constante . No obstante, asi como está no compilaría, por lo tanto, no sé como puedes ejecutar ese código a menos que no sea la versión que dices. Corrigiendo el problema la ventana sale con el titulo "Holaaa".

Comment: Si lo haces *normal*, sin la función `Asignar`, funciona bien? Si es así, el problema debe estar en la función `Asignar`.

Comment: La funcion asignar reemplaza a esta función `LoadStringW(hInstance, IDS_APP_TITLE, szTitle, MAX_LOADSTRING);` y lo que hace es, en un arreglo de 100 caracteres, coloca en las primeras posiciones los caracteres que forman el titulo, en el inspetror de elementos se ve que se copian todos los caracteres a la cadena pero no se como pasar al cadena completa ya que solo esta tomando el primer caracter

Comment: Si hago uso de `LPCWSTR` o de `LPWSTR` la función `CreateWindowW(...` retorna null, entonces ni siquiera muestra ventana

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft es muy especialito con sus interfaces, tanto que si te sales de su uso *esperado*, puedes tener comportamientos inesperados, puedes leer sobre el uso correcto de las cadenas en la API de Windows en [este enlace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/working-with-strings).

Por suerte el comportamiento que describes es muy fácil de explicar (aunque puede que no sea fácil de corregir):

La diferencia entre un carácter ancho y uno estrecho es su tamaño. En Windows el primero (`wchar_t`) es de 16bits y el segundo (`char`) es de 8bits, por lo que la misma cadena con diferentes tipos tiene este aspecto:

###### Cadena `"hola"` con `char` en bytes:

| 0 | 1 | 2 | 4 | 5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `h` | `o` | `l` | `a` | 0 |

###### Cadena `L"hola"` con `wchar_t` en bytes:

| 0 | 1 | 2 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | A |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `h` | 0 | `o` | 0 | `l` | 0 | `a` | 0 | 0 | 0 |

Si a una función que espera una cadena de caracteres estrechos (`char`) le pasas una cadena de caracteres anchos (`wchar_t`) va a mostrar sólo la primera letra pues después de ésta se va a encontrar el final de la cadena (el `0`).

---

Windows no quiere "*complicarnos la vida*" haciéndonos decidir que tipo de cadena de caracteres debemos usar; para "*facilitarnos*" la tarea nos permite definir (o no) la macro `UNICODE` y en base si está definida o no las funciones de la API esperarán recibir caracteres estrechos o anchos.

Pero eso sólo funciona si programamos como Windows espera que lo hagamos, por lo tanto:

- No debe usarse `WCHAR` que siempre es un alias de `wchar_t` si no `TCHAR` que es un alias de `char` o `wchar_t` dependiendo de la macro `UNICODE`.
- No debe usarse `wcslen` para calcular la longitud de una cadena, si no `_tcslen` que es `strlen` o `wcslen` dependiendo de la macro `UNICODE`.
- No deben escribirse literales de texto con `L""` o `""` si no con `_T("")` ya que la macro `_T` cambia el literal de ancho a estrecho dependiendo de la macro `UNICODE`.
- No deben llamarse las funciones `xxxxxW` (por ejemplo `CreateWindowW`) o `xxxxxA` si no las funciones `xxxxx` ya que estas se *transformarán* en `xxxxxW` o `xxxxxA` dependiendo de la macro `UNICODE`.

Si tienes en cuenta esas limitaciones de la API de Windows, probablemente tu problema se solucione.